# A compact subspace of a Banach space must have a finite dimension?

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $A \subset X$ a compact subspace. Doesn't this necessarily imply that $A$ is finite-dimensional? I've read that this is not true, but I can't figure out why my reasoning is incorrect.

***<s>Wrong</s> proof.*** If $A$ is compact and $X$ is a Banach space (i.e complete metric space), then $A$ is closed in $X$ and totally bounded. Since $A$ is closed in $X$, it's complete with respect to the restriction of metric $d_{A \times A \to \mathbb{R}}$ induced by the norm of $X$. Since $(A, d)$ is complete and totally bounded, it's sequentially compact (i.e every sequence in $A$ has a convergent subsequence in $A$), which is more than what we need to show that unit ball is compact and $\dim A < \infty$.

Where did I go wrong? Thanks.

Comment: A compact subspace must be finite dimensional. However, a compact subset does not have to be contained in a finite dimensional subspace. An example would be $|a_k| <= \frac{1}{k^2}$ in $l_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assertion is true, and the proof can be shortened even more: the unit ball is closed in $A$, so if $A$ is compact, so is the unit ball, hence $A$ is finite dimensional.

Anyway, it doesn't really matter because only the zero subspace is compact.  Every nonzero subspace $E$ of $X$ admits at least one continuous, surjective linear map $E \rightarrow k$, where $k = \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, so $E$ cannot be compact.

Comment: Thanks! Last assertion follows from Hahn-Banach, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure.  If you find out, let me know

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that every compact subset of a Banach space is finite dimensional. Let $H$ be  a Hilber psace with orthnormal basis $(e_n)$. Then $\{0,\frac {e_1} 1,\frac {e_2}2,\frac {e_3} 3...\}$ is a compact set which is not contained in any finite dimensional subsapce of $H$.

Comment: A subset has no "dimension" anyway and the last line part in the question (sequentially compact $\implies \dim A < \infty$) has no meaning without vector space structure. But your statement and example are correct.